# Словообразование глаголов

Tags: словообразование

Одинаковый ли способ словообразования у глаголов *выигрывать*, *подпрыгивать*, *переваривать*, *постукивать*, *разливать*?

Answer (score 1):

**Постукивать** -- приставочно-суффиксальный способ образования:

**стук**ать -> **по**+стук+**ива**+ть.

Остальные глаголы образованы суффиксальным способом от соотв. глаголов сов. вида.